# How to design 'open' and 'archive' tables for same object with Java JPA?

Tags: java, spring-boot, jpa

I'm building a Java Spring Boot micro-service that has an object that represents a business transaction that I am mapping to a SQL database via JPA. The object has a 'state' property with two values of 'open' and 'completed'.  Given the large data volumes associated with this object I want to move objects with a state equal to 'completed' to an archive table. The ideal solution is to have two tables: one 'live' table for objects that are open or only recently completed, and a second table for archived completed objects.

Any suggestions of how I can do this with JPA?  I also want to have a facility to join the 'live' and 'archive' tables for running queries across all data.

TIA

Comment: Which database are you using? One approach is to do partitioning in the database, and have the application only see a single table, even though the physical data layout is dependent on the state property.

Comment: No database chosen yet - it will probably be either MySQL or Postgres. I'd prefer two tables.  I'm envisaging the use of a scheduled task to move 'completed' records from the 'Live' to the 'Archive' tables

Answer (score -3):

I'm building a Java Spring Boot micro-service that has an object that represents a business transaction that I am mapping to a SQL database via JPA. The object has a 'state' property with two values of 'open' and 'completed'. Given the large data volumes associated with this object I want to move objects with a state equal to 'completed' to an archive table. The ideal solution is to have two tables: one 'live' table for objects that are open or only recently completed, and a second table for archived completed objects.

Any suggestions of how I can do this with JPA? I also want to have a facility to join the 'live' and 'archive' tables for running queries across all data.

Comment: If you have a new question, please ask it by clicking the [Ask Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask) button. Include a link to this question if it helps provide context. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/30129252)